# The inverse of a function.

Tags: functions, inverse-function

I am unable to reach the inverse function of $$\frac{x}{2x+1}$$

For $y=\frac{x}{2x+1}$ I tried, but I am still unable to match the answer according to my book, which is  $$\frac{x}{1-2x}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please learn how to format math for this site. See [help](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). You might also like to take the [Tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: This time I have edited it for you. Please look to see what I changed the double \$\$ gives bigger centred math text, the single \$ is for ordinary math text. Note that you must put the \$ at the beginning and end of each math part.

Comment: The answer in your book, $y=\dfrac{x}{1-2x}$ is the inverse of the function $y=\dfrac{x}{2x+1}$. So perhaps there was a misprint in the question and the original function was supposed to be $y=\dfrac{x}{2x+1}$ instead of $y=\dfrac{1}{2x+1}$.

Comment: Even thought there is a misprint could you please help me reach the solution

Comment: What did you triy and what failed ?

Answer (score 4):

$$f\left( x \right) =\frac { 1 }{ 2x+1 } \\ 2x+1=\frac { 1 }{ f\left( x \right)  } \\ x=\frac { \frac { 1 }{ f\left( x \right)  } -1 }{ 2 } =\frac { 1-f\left( x \right)  }{ 2f\left( x \right)  } $$
so

> $$f^{ -1 }\left( x \right) =\frac { 1-x }{ 2x } $$

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a Moebius transformation $z\mapsto gz=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ for the invertible matrix $g=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \cr c & d \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ of determinant $1$. The inverse mapping is given by $z\mapsto g^{-1}z$. Since $g^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr -2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, this inverse map is $$z\mapsto \frac{z}{1-2z}.$$

Edit: There was a typo with the first map (the determinant of the former matrix was not equal $1$).

Comment: Any simpler method please thanks

Comment: Inverting this matrix is really simple:)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x}{2x+1}=y$$
$$\implies\frac{2x+1}{x}=\frac{1}{y}$$
$$\implies\frac{2x}{x}+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{y}$$
$$\implies\ 2+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{y}$$
$$\implies\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{y}-2$$
$$\implies\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1-2y}{y}$$
$$\implies f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x}{1-2x}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\frac x{2x+1}$$
$$y=\frac1{2+\dfrac1x}$$
$$\frac1y=2+\frac1x$$
$$\frac1y-2=\frac1x$$
$$\frac1{\dfrac1y-2}=x$$
$$\frac y{1-2y}=x$$

Answer (score 0):

To find the inverse switch $y$ and $x$ then solve for $y$.

Comment: I tried still unable

Comment: Your book's answer is wrong. For eg. if $x=0$ then $y=1$. But if the inverse is $y=x/(1-2x)$ then when $x=1$ $y=-1\neq 0$.

Comment: This is neither a criticization nor a request of clarification. This describes the procedure.